# Filtering products with required category ID's and OR category ID's

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `categories` table (category_id, category_name) with the following type categories:

```
Website1
Website2
Product_type1
Product_type2
red
blue
green
wood
plastic
metal
```

A `products` table (prod_id, prod_name... etc.) and a link table `product_cateogries` (id, prod_id, category_id).

I'm trying to run a query to filter these values, but some categories are required, and some are X or X. For example, I want to be able to select all `Website1` and `Product_type2` products that are either red or blue.

My first thought was that I could `IN (Product_type2_id, Website2_id, red_id, blue_id)` but that makes `Product_type2_id` and `Website2_id` optional when they should be required. And using `GROUP BY prod_id HAVING count(distinct category_id) = 4)` ensures all colours_id are found, when a product can only have one colour. Is a subquery needed somehow?

TABLES:

category:

```
id (int)
category_name (varchar)
```

product_category:

```
id (int)
product_id, (int)
category_id (int)
```

Products:

```
prod_id (int)
prod_image
prod_price
```

SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32ec8

UPDATE:

The below query now does exactly what I want, seems a little messy though and like there should be a cleaner way?

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_category pc_w1 ON pc_w1.product_id = p.prod_id AND pc_w1.category_id = 3
LEFT JOIN product_category pc_pt2 ON pc_pt2.product_id = p.prod_id AND pc_pt2.category_id = 1
LEFT JOIN product_category pc_rb ON pc_rb.product_id = p.prod_id AND pc_rb.category_id IN (11)
LEFT JOIN product_category pc_rb1 ON pc_rb1.product_id = p.prod_id AND pc_rb1.category_id IN (1,12)
WHERE
  pc_w1.product_id IS NOT NULL AND pc_pt2.product_id IS NOT NULL AND 
  (
    pc_rb.product_id IS NOT NULL AND
    pc_rb1.product_id IS NOT NULL 
  )
GROUP BY p.prod_id
```

Comment: Show the schemas of the tables. Also, how do you know which are required and which are optional? Is the info in the tables, or just part of the query?

Comment: I cant see where to print out all the schema but I've added all the data you should need to the question.

Comment: What about the rest of the questions?

Comment: @SloanThrasher - Required and optional field ID's are passed in from the PHP side.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry thanks - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32ec8

Comment: Thanks for the progress report.

Comment: Thanks for helping @Strawberry

Comment: How my query is messy? This is as clean as you'll get. I understand you **really** want only one join but I don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use joins

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_category pc_w1 ON 
  pc_w1.product_id = p.prod_id AND pc_w1.category_id = 3
LEFT JOIN product_category pc_pt2 ON 
  pc_pt2.product_id = p.prod_id AND pc_pt2.category_id = 7
LEFT JOIN product_category pc_rb ON
  pc_rb.product_id = p.prod_id AND pc_rb.category_id IN (9,13) -- black/blue
WHERE
  pc_w1.product_id IS NOT NULL OR
  (
    pc_pt2.product_id IS NOT NULL AND
    pc_rb.product_id IS NOT NULL
  )
GROUP BY p.prod_id
```

Edit: I see you added fiddle so here is my working example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/837872/4

Comment: Where is the manual/tutorial/resource that recommends the inclusion of a `GROUP BY` at the end of every query?

Comment: @Strawberry recommends? OP wants list of products and without `group by` he will get duplicated products produces by query above

Comment: So far better to return indeterminate and possibly nonsensical results.

Comment: @Strawberry please explain. OP wants all products from Website1 OR (Product_type2 AND Red or blue), this query would do exactly what he wants

Comment: @john I added example

Comment: Thanks @Peter that seemed to have done the job! Is there any way to clean up the 3/7 individual joins? It seems like there should be a way to combine them, but I've had a play with `HAVING` and can't seem to get anything better?

Comment: @john this is good solution, performance wise. only `UNION` could a little faster (because you use `OR` in `WHERE`). query is pretty clean and straight forward, you pick items that occurs in `product_category` with certain condition that's it